# How does victory point system work?

Tags: company-of-heroes-2

In CoH2 there are victory capture points represented on the mini map by star icons.  Normally there are 3 of these and in standard matches teams start with 500/500 victory points.

**How does the victory point system deduct points from your victory point score?**

---

Side Note:

I just played a game where I held the 3 victory points until I still had 500/500 vp and my opponent had 44/500 vp.  My opponent made a force I couldn't counter and captured 2 of the 3 vp's.  I was content to play defensively until i realized i only had 100/500 vp and he still had 44/500 vp over 15 minutes later.  I am very confused on how that is supposed to work, how come he wasnt losing half the amount of vp's when I held one vp capture point?  and yes I lost the game

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for your victory point score to reduce **your opponent must hold more victory points than you**, and visa-versa (so for your opponents victory score to reduce, you must hold more victory points than your opponent).

The rate at which the victory score reduces depends on the number of points each side controls - for example if one side holds all 3 victory points then the rate at which the score reduces will be much greater than if one side holds 2 points.

Answer (score 1):

The point system works like this. When you have the majority of the points under your control the opponent's 500/500 points begin to decrease. When your opponents capture the majority of the points your 500/500 points begin to decrease. Once the points reach 50/500 they begin to deteriorate at half the normal speed. This continues back and forth till one player hits 0/500 in which the opposing player wins.